# How to train model using TFSlim library?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision

I'm reading Object Detection API source code and I wonder how to use TFSlim to train model?

More specifically, when we use Tensorflow to train the model, we use something like this:

```
parameters = model(X_train, Y_train, X_test, Y_test)
# Returns: parameters -- parameters learnt by the model. 
# They can then be used to predict.
```

And to predict the result, we use something like:

```
y_image_prediction = predict(my_image, parameters)
```

But in file trainer.py, we don't have something like above, we only get:

```
slim.learning.train(
    train_tensor,
    logdir=train_dir,
    master=master,
    is_chief=is_chief,
    session_config=session_config,
    startup_delay_steps=train_config.startup_delay_steps,
    init_fn=init_fn,
    summary_op=summary_op,
    number_of_steps=(
        train_config.num_steps if train_config.num_steps else None),
    save_summaries_secs=120,
    sync_optimizer=sync_optimizer,
    saver=saver)
```

And there are no return about this `slim.learning.train` function. So I wonder what is the using of `slim.learning.train` function, and how do we get the parameters -- that can be used to predict the result?

[HERE](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/legacy/trainer.py) is source code of trainer.py.

Answer (score 0):

The `train` function does not return a value because it modifies the actual parameters of the model. The function does that by running the `train_tensor` which is: "A `Tensor` that, when executed, will apply the gradients and return the loss value." as written in the [function documentation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py#L565).

The tensor the documentation talks about what you get when you tell an optimizer to optimize some cost function. It is `opt_op` in the following example:

```py
opt = GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate=0.1)
opt_op = opt.minimize(cost)
```

Find more in the [optimizer documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/Optimizer).

Comment: So how do I get the `parameters` back so I can use that `parameters` to predict the result while `slim.learning.train` do not return that `parameters`?

Comment: What exactly do you call parameters? I understood that by parameters you mean TensorFlow Variable objects. They are modified during the training, i.e., the same Variable objects have different values.

Comment: So how do we predict the result after training the model? The `parameters` is the `trained weight` that will be used to predict the output. For exp, I used `y_image_prediction = predict(my_image, parameters) ` to predict the result. So how do I do this with TFSlim?

Comment: There must be some tensors that are inputs to your model (either `tf.Dataset` or some placeholders) and a tensor that is the output of your model. You run this tensor in a session.

Comment: In my case, I think `train_tensor` is the input tensor, right? But I want to find the output tensor that hold the learnt weight from the model and can be used for prediction.